# open any PDF in any folder with Acrobat

Tags: pdf, location, acrobat

I'd like to open a pdf from whatever location with Acrobat Pro. I have found scripts that open files on my desktop, but what I would like to have is the possibility to open any pdf in whatever location with Acrobat.

How do I go about?

(And before anyone asks: there's a bug in Acrobat XI that somehow messes with the doubleclick feature to open pdfs. So it seems a good idea to have applescript command that.)

Comment: Is Acrobat Pro the default program you use for opening pdfs? Check one of the file properties to make sure. Otherwise, I'd try reinstalling Acrobat XI

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *whatever location*? Maybe share the script that now works for opening the file from the desktop?

Comment: And did you [try this](http://answers.acrobatusers.com/can-open-adobe-file-double-click-message-Acrobat-open-files-Adobe-PDF-document-forma-q4102.aspx). I would do the process twice, first set it to something else, maybe Photoshop, then try Acrobat.